# xml dom parsing using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

i'm completely new to javascript. I need a code in javascript that reads an external xml file and logs each value into the console. Does the following code miss something like loading the file into the html page?

```
<html>
<xml id="obj" src="books.xml"></xml>
<script>
    console.log(obj);
    var rootnode=document.documentElement;
    for(var i=0;i<rootnode.childNode.childNodes.length;++i)
        for(var j=0;j<rootnode.childNode.childNodes.length;++j)
            {
                console.log(rootnode.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].nodeValue);
            }
</script>
</html>
```

The books.xml file looks like this

```
<books>
<book id="b1">
    <name>Java</name>
    <author>Gosling</author>
    <price>600</price>
</book>
<book id="b2">
    <name>Javascript</name>
    <author>Brandon</author>
    <price>400</price>
</book>
</books>
```

Comment: will need to use ajax for this, there is no `<xml>` tag in html

Comment: possible without ajax?

Comment: can make an xslt page, depends on what other html you need and if you have a dynamic server language available to build the page if you are combining the 2

Comment: Should load the xml file using something like this xmlhttp.open("GET",'filepath');
And then do XML parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You actually *can* do this without ajax, contrary to comments.  The way to do it is to us an `iframe`, which you can set to hidden if you would like.

Consider an html document like yours, except with the iframe:

```
<html>
  <head><title>whatever</title></head>
  <body>
    <iframe id='data' src='books.xml'></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Your javascript function can then be something like this:

```
function getData(){
  var dataFrame = document.getElementById('data');
  // older versions of IE needed this guard
  var xml = dataFrame.contentDocument || dataFrame.contentWindow.document; 
  var books = xml.getElementsByTagName('book');
  // books is iterable, and you can further extract nodes from it just like HTML tags
  for (var i=0;i<books.length; i++) {
    console.log(books[i]);
  }
}
```